# Loudness equalizer for ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, apt, sound, speakers

I have recently switched from windows to ubuntu and i like to listen music while work but in ubuntu i have to consistently change the volume due to no option for loudness equalizer is there any program available for it.I am using vlc media player

Comment: Vlc has its own equalizer. Go to Settings, switch to Advanced Mode, switch to Detailed View and go to `Audio > Filters` option.

Answer (score -1):

you can try PulseAudio Equilizer.

Down load it here https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webupd8/zesty/main/base/pulseaudio-equalizer

Then open a terminal, and type:

```
cd /downloads
sudo dpkg -i pulseaudio-equilizer_2.7.0-5-webupd8-xenial0_all.deb
```

Comment: This is an Equaliser, not a loudness equaliser. they're completely different things.